# How to follow/debug html creation in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, episerver

I'm trying to find out where an extra div is inserted and how I would go about removing it.

In our `Index.cshtml` file we have this:

```
<div id="an-id">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BottomArticleListContentArea, new { ViewName = "_ArticleListBlockNoHeader" })
</div>
```

And in our `_ArticleListBlockNoHeader.cshtml` view the code looks like this:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var article = Model.Items[i];
        <div class="item" data-articleid="@article.ArticleId">
        Item @article.ArticleId
        </div>
    }
}
```

BottomArticleListContentArea is a `ContentArea` and is handled by this DisplayTemplate:

```
@model ContentArea
@if (Model != null)
{
    Html.RenderContentArea(Model);
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't really do anything except check if it's null. Oh... Maybe it does more things!

When I look at the generated html it looks like this:

```
<div id="an-id">
<div><div>

    <div class="item" data-articleid="1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item" data-articleid="2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item" data-articleid="3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item" data-articleid="4">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item" data-articleid="5">Item 5</div>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Notice how on row **2** and **9** there is two divs (`<div><div>` and `</div></div>`) that are not in the code I just shared above.

My hypothesis is now that these two divs might be added by some extension method somewhere or some handler or something else. I'm not familiar with the entire codebase and I'm fairly new with ASP.net so my knowledge of the insertion points in ASP.net is very limited.

Where could these two divs come from? And how can I start looking for them?

If something is missing in the question, please let me know, tried to be brief so that it would be easier to read and understand

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Made a mistake while cleaning the code, added back so that the result is what's generated by the code.

The HTML results above is what is returned and captured using fiddler. No JS has started running while the DOM is recorded.

Added the display template used.

Comment: The display template code as well is needed here, if you are using a customized one. Also Did you posted all the relevant razor View code in question here? Since in the generated html I can see first pair or unwanted divs not terminated properly (`<div><div>`) while it is in the last pair?

Comment: Does `BottomArticleListContentArea` has any data as `html` in it , also did you check any script in your code adding that extra div , can you show your sample `ActionMethod` to know what  `Model.Items`  has as data ?

Comment: Your also claiming that the `<div>` elements generated by the partial include some text (`"Item 1"` etc) but the code you have shown does not generate that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It really helped and I have now some more investigation to do around the "RenderContentArea" thing. I'll update this page with whatever I find or add an answer if I find out the issue.

Comment: In Index.cshtml you can remove `<div id="an-id">` and change to `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BottomArticleListContentArea, new { Id = "an-id", ViewName = "_ArticleListBlockNoHeader" })` That will remove one of the divs at least.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `@Html.PropertyFor()` instead? I wrote a blog post about making Episerver property rendering more consistent http://dodavinkeln.se/post/make-propertyfor()-more-consistent and a follow-up http://dodavinkeln.se/post/propertyfor()-revisited. If you're using `ProperyFor` instead you don't need the display template for ContentArea.

Comment: @JohanPetersson No, no particular reason. Thanks for the links. After reading your posts I don't feel closer to a solution unfortunately. It still sounds as if I should use `DisplayFor` and not `PropertyFor` since this is something I never want to render differently, and I'm not very keen on overriding the property rendered wihth "overly complicated" code :/ I tested simply changing `DisplayFor` to `PropertyFor`, with no apparent difference when looking at the DOM generated. Same amount of divs. Also tried moving the Id, no difference independent if I had `DisplayFor()` or `PropertyFor()` :(

Comment: If you read my blog post you would know that Episerver ALWAYS wraps content areas with one div for the property and one div for each item, unless you specify it to render another element than a div. You have to work with it, and not against it :) So by moving the `id` into `additionalViewData` is one way, you can also move `item` class by specifying ChildrenCssClass in `additionalViewData`.

Comment: You also want to use `PropertyFor` to make the property editable for editors.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use any "overly complicated code" then this is they way to go. That's how Episerver is intended to be used. I didn't mean that you should use the code in my blog posts, but read the reasoning behind why there are extra markup rendered. My post was actually covering how to always force this behavior for property types.

Comment: @JohanPetersson I did read your post, and as you said, it states that EPiServer wraps content areas in a div and one for each item. That I found out previously based on the comment from Siva :) I tried moving the id into additionalViewData as you said, and pre earlier comment I saw absolutely no difference to the generated html. Then I better understand what your posts were meant to illustrate and teach, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @JohanPetersson I did manage to set a class to the first div by using `CssClass = "aclass"` I haven't yet found out how to set the id. Thanks for your updated comment I now better understand what your comments were meant to illustrate and teach, thanks for the clarification and time you put into helping me with my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the current solution that I have right now and I'm going to try out for a while:

(highly EPiServer specific)

Instead of letting it be rendered using `RenderContentArea` we're taking control over it and creating it the "raw" way with `RenderContentData`

```
foreach (var content in Model.FilteredItems)
{
    Html.RenderContentData(content.GetContent(), false, Model.Tag);
}
```

This gets rid of all the extra divs and make it behave just the way we want it, just the way it seen when we read the code. 
Yes, with this we're also loosing the ability to edit the page directly in epi visually. But that's something we need to look into later, for now, it works and I'm happy.

I also wrote this extended version that lets me choose if I want to skip the wrappers or not like this (notice `DisableWrapper = true`)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ContentArea, new { DisableWrapper = true, ViewName = "_ArticleList" })
```

That can be done if I instead change the first code snippet to this:

```
var disableWrapper = Html.ViewContext.ViewData["DisableWrapper"] as bool?;

if (disableWrapper.GetValueOrDefault())
{
    foreach (var content in Model.FilteredItems)
    {
        Html.RenderContentData(content.GetContent(), false, Model.Tag);
    }
}
else
{
    Html.RenderContentArea(Model);
}
```

This works and seems to produce the results I'm looking for. As stated previously, I haven't worked in this field for that long so if there's any suggestions or tips, I'd love to hear that and be able to improve my solution both here and in the project.

Thanks for the helpful comments that made me finally arrive at this solution!

Comment: I see you found a solution, but just out of curiosity, did you try using `PropertyFor ` and adding additional parameter like so `@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.BottomArticleListContentArea, new
{ CustomTag = "ul", CssClass = "list", ChildrenCustomTagName = "li", ChildrenCssClass = "item" })` ?

Comment: Hi @Frostrar, I hadn't tried that approach. I just did now though and it produces very interesting results! How did you know about using the CustomTag CssClass and those specific keys for ViewData? I've searched but not found it documented. I'd be super grateful if you could share that resource :) It really helped me learn new things, but didn't really help me remove those divs (tried with empty string).

Comment: have a look at this link [http://www.jondjones.com/learn-episerver-cms/episerver-developers-guide/episerver-content-areas/how-to-make-your-blocks-render-correctly-within-episerver-10-content-areas]